# Is $x \mapsto P_x(A)$ measurable for a measure $P_x$ determined by transition kernels $(\delta_x,P_i)_{i \ge 0}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a sequence $P_i$ of transition kernels from $(E,\mathcal B(E)$
to $(E,\mathcal B(E))$ and $\delta_x$ the Dirac delta measure for the
point $x\in E$, it follows from the Ionescu-Tulcea theorem that for
every $x$ there exists a unique measure $P_x$ which is consistent with
the $n $ dimensional distributions  $B \mapsto \int \delta_x(d x_o) \int...\int P_n(x_{n-1},d
x_n)1_B(x_0,...,x_n))$

> My question is: Given an abitrary collection of measures $P_x$  on some measurable space $(E, \mathcal E )$ and some $A \in \mathcal E $ would it be true that the map $x \mapsto P_x(A)$ is measurable. If not is it then true in the present situation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I believe I may answer the second question of my own post! If we treat $\delta_x $ as a kernel given by $(x,A) \mapsto  \delta_x (A), \ (x,A) \in (E, \mathcal E)$ the result follows as proved by saz [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223318/introducing-a-product-measure-from-a-sequence-of-transition-kernels).